# Why is my citrus bare on one side?

Tags: citrus

[image: bare branch on citrus]

All the branches on the east facing side of the tree are bare of leaves. I haven't noticed any pests going for it. I've been fertalising with Osmocote, citrus liquid fertaliser and have recently been giving it iron chelate to counter the pale leaves.

No flowers on this one either, my other citrus do.

Comment: What's the lumpy brown stuff on top of the soil behind the stem on the citrus tree in the photo? Is it late spring there or summer,  and were those stems devoid of leaves last year as well?

Answer (score 3):

Do you see all the buds on the branches?  You don't have any problems other than, yes those plants look a bit anemic.  Iron might not be the answer.  Osmocote should be fine (14-14-14 or 16-16-16).  Too much nitrogen relative to the Phosphorus and Potassium would cause more vegetative growth than reproductive growth.  I am concerned that you use another fertilizer! How often have you applied Osmocote?  What is the formulation for this citrus fertilizer?  Did you know that plants make their own food and fertilizer IS NOT FOOD.  Too much fertilizer will kill plants sure as Sunday (or however that cliche is worded).

The soil looks like potting soil that has been sterilized, yes?  If it is garden soil, please let us know.  The fertilizer I am seeing in these pictures is the proper amount for 4 to 6 months.  Please tell us the last time you applied fertilizer, how much and what the formulation of the Citrus fertilizer you have used. Is this the first time you used Osmocote?  Do not ADD anything else without a proper soil test. Don't add IRON or Gypsum or fish fertilizer (a very weak fertilizer/micronutrient that benefits plants by making them HARDIER). I have a feeling you are babying these guys possibly to death.

And I wouldn't be staking my baby saplings!!  Staking is just like a cast on your arm causing atrophy.  Movement by that stem in the wind is what causes a thicker, stouter trunk and promotes SUPPORT ROOTS.  Let those baby plants move!!

Use ONLY the Osmocote.  Too much fertilizer will cause a build up of salts in your soil and plant leaves will look like this.  Leave them alone for awhile.  Osmocote is SLOW RELEASE far better for plants in my opinion than fast release.  Please tell us exactly what you've been doing for fertilizer.  You might have to flush the soil...but depending on how much you have used, how long ago, these guys might just be fine.  Lots of buds, that little sapling is NOT bare on one side, not at all.  I might have come to the conclusion a bit of iron is necessary just like you did.  I'd go back and check the fertilizer I'd been using to see if there was iron included.  Remember, there are signs for deficiencies and signs of excess 'nutrients'...chemicals. Too much is far worse than too little!!